# How to segment an image using `mat2cell()` and display the resultant image using matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using `mat2cell()` function to segment the image. But I don't know how the display the resultant image.

This is my code:

```
I = imread('input2.jpg');
J = rgb2gray(I);
K = imresize(J,[128 128]);
[x,y] = size(K);
disp([x,y]);
C = mat2cell(K,[32,32,32,32],[32,32,32,32]);
celldisp(C);
```

This is the image I'm feeding as the input:

[image]

Is there any other way to solve this? Do I have to change my code? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, at the end of this C is a cell array - to display each as an image, you should iterate through C and imshow() the resulting array:

```
imshow(C{1})
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. Is there any way, so that I can put each segmented image to a specific variables and can perform further operations?

Comment: @user3483746 Use `data = cat(3,C{:})` and thus each 3D slice of `data` would be one cropped image.

Comment: @Divakar Is it possible for me to place all these sliced image in a single `axes` ?

Comment: @user3483746, yes, definitely. This will require using subplots: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html